# When is entropic ward considered "used"?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

Entropic Ward is a patron of the old god feature that allows the warlock to impose disadvantage on an attack against him as a reaction. If the target misses, the warlock can give himself advantage when attacking that creature until the end of his next turn.

The PHB says that (pg. 110)

> Once you use this feature, you can't use it again until you finish a
>   short or long rest.

When is it considered used? Can I only impose disadvantage with the hopes of a miss once per short or long rest, or is it only expended once I gain advantage?

My gut tells me the former, but I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A wider quotation makes the intent quite clear:

> When a creature makes an attack
>   roll against you, you can use your reaction to impose
>   disadvantage on that roll. If the attack misses you, your
>   next attack roll against the creature has advantage if you
>   make it before the end of your next turn.
>
> Once you use this feature, you can’t use it again until
>   you finish a short or long rest.

You "use" this feature when you "use your reaction to impose
disadvantage"; at that point you have received a distinct benefit (disadvantage on the attack). What follows are further consequences of the "use" - you get advantage if they miss but not if they hit.

Answer (score 4):

By my reading it would indeed be the former. Entropic ward is a defensive feature with a conditional buff on the probable counterattack.